# Item passed into the delete method don't delete completely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

In my  project when i  want delete a news group it don't delete .

This is "Delete" method body :

```
enter code public bool DeleteGroup(PageGroup pageGroup)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(pageGroup).State=EntityState.Deleted;
         
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This will call Delete method from controller :

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.GroupID })
```

This is Delete action in controller :

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
       PageGroup pageGroup = PageGroupRepository.GetGroupById(id.Value);
        PageGroupRepository.DeleteGroup(pageGroup);
     
        if (pageGroup == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(pageGroup);
    }
```

This is delete button :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit"  value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Where is the problem ?delete button or delete method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to save the changes after deleting:

```
public bool DeleteGroup(PageGroup pageGroup)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(pageGroup).State=EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```